# Creating XML file gives internal server error

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, .htaccess

I am using wordpress extension to create XML file output. However only (very small) part of output si generated properly. If I try to access that XML from another site (I need XML and that site to connect together) I get an 500 internal server error respond from site. Here is part of error log:

```
www.auto-flex.eu [Wed May 21 18:58:35.078213 2014] [-:error] [pid 9298] [client 92.240.253.180:54919] PHP Warning:  fopen(/nfsmnt/hosting1_2/0/3/031ab609-b23c-40f3-8d1b-6700b9221820/auto-flex.eu/web/wp-content/plugins/ankona-fields-polia/polia.php) [<a href='function.fopen'>function.fopen</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /nfsmnt/hosting1_2/0/3/031ab609-b23c-40f3-8d1b-6700b9221820/auto-flex.eu/web/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3879, referer http://www.auto-flex.eu/wp-admin/admin.php?page=heureka-feed/feed.php
www.auto-flex.eu [Wed May 21 18:58:35.078467 2014] [-:error] [pid 9298] [client 92.240.253.180:54919] PHP Warning:  fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /nfsmnt/hosting1_2/0/3/031ab609-b23c-40f3-8d1b-6700b9221820/auto-flex.eu/web/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3882, referer http://www.auto-flex.eu/wp-admin/admin.php?page=heureka-feed/feed.php
www.auto-flex.eu [Wed May 21 18:58:35.078590 2014] [-:error] [pid 9298] [client 92.240.253.180:54919] PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /nfsmnt/hosting1_2/0/3/031ab609-b23c-40f3-8d1b-6700b9221820/auto-flex.eu/web/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3885, referer http://www.auto-flex.eu/wp-admin/admin.php?page=heureka-feed/feed.php
www.auto-flex.eu [Wed May 21 18:58:35.379629 2014] [-:error] [pid 9298] [client 92.240.253.180:54919] PHP Warning:  fopen(/nfsmnt/hosting1_2/0/3/031ab609-b23c-40f3-8d1b-6700b9221820/auto-flex.eu/web/wp-content/plugins/ankona-fields-polia/polia.php) [<a href='function.fopen'>function.fopen</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /nfsmnt/hosting1_2/0/3/031ab609-b23c-40f3-8d1b-6700b9221820/auto-flex.eu/web/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3879, referer http://www.auto-flex.eu/wp-admin/admin.php?page=heureka-feed/feed.php
www.auto-flex.eu [Wed May 21 18:58:35.379744 2014] [-:error] [pid 9298] [client 92.240.253.180:54919] PHP Warning:  fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /nfsmnt/hosting1_2/0/3/031ab609-b23c-40f3-8d1b-6700b9221820/auto-flex.eu/web/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3882, referer http://www.auto-flex.eu/wp-admin/admin.php?page=heureka-feed/feed.php
www.auto-flex.eu [Wed May 21 18:58:35.379803 2014] [-:error] [pid 9298] [client 92.240.253.180:54919] PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /nfsmnt/hosting1_2/0/3/031ab609-b23c-40f3-8d1b-6700b9221820/auto-flex.eu/web/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3885, referer http://www.auto-flex.eu/wp-admin/admin.php?page=heureka-feed/feed.php
www.auto-flex.eu [Wed May 21 19:00:38.025588 2014] [-:error] [pid 9364] [client 92.240.253.180:59625] PHP Warning:  fopen(/nfsmnt/hosting1_2/0/3/031ab609-b23c-40f3-8d1b-6700b9221820/auto-flex.eu/web/wp-content/plugins/ankona-fields-polia/polia.php) [<a href='function.fopen'>function.fopen</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /nfsmnt/hosting1_2/0/3/031ab609-b23c-40f3-8d1b-6700b9221820/auto-flex.eu/web/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3879, referer http://www.auto-flex.eu/wp-admin/admin.php?page=heureka-feed/feed.php
www.auto-flex.eu [Wed May 21 19:00:38.025663 2014] [-:error] [pid 9364] [client 92.240.253.180:59625] PHP Warning:  fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /nfsmnt/hosting1_2/0/3/031ab609-b23c-40f3-8d1b-6700b9221820/auto-flex.eu/web/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3882, referer http://www.auto-flex.eu/wp-admin/admin.php?page=heureka-feed/feed.php
www.auto-flex.eu [Wed May 21 19:00:38.025708 2014] [-:error] [pid 9364] [client 92.240.253.180:59625] PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /nfsmnt/hosting1_2/0/3/031ab609-b23c-40f3-8d1b-6700b9221820/auto-flex.eu/web/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3885, referer http://www.auto-flex.eu/wp-admin/admin.php?page=heureka-feed/feed.php
www.auto-flex.eu [Wed May 21 19:00:38.138559 2014] [-:error] [pid 9364] [client 92.240.253.180:59625] PHP Warning:  fopen(/nfsmnt/hosting1_2/0/3/031ab609-b23c-40f3-8d1b-6700b9221820/auto-flex.eu/web/wp-content/plugins/ankona-fields-polia/polia.php) [<a href='function.fopen'>function.fopen</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /nfsmnt/hosting1_2/0/3/031ab609-b23c-40f3-8d1b-6700b9221820/auto-flex.eu/web/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3879, referer http://www.auto-flex.eu/wp-admin/admin.php?page=heureka-feed/feed.php
www.auto-flex.eu [Wed May 21 19:00:38.138630 2014] [-:error] [pid 9364] [client 92.240.253.180:59625] PHP Warning:  fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /nfsmnt/hosting1_2/0/3/031ab609-b23c-40f3-8d1b-6700b9221820/auto-flex.eu/web/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3882, referer http://www.auto-flex.eu/wp-admin/admin.php?page=heureka-feed/feed.php
www.auto-flex.eu [Wed May 21 19:00:38.138672 2014] [-:error] [pid 9364] [client 92.240.253.180:59625] PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /nfsmnt/hosting1_2/0/3/031ab609-b23c-40f3-8d1b-6700b9221820/auto-flex.eu/web/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3885, referer http://www.auto-flex.eu/wp-admin/admin.php?page=heureka-feed/feed.php
```

I know that these are only PHP warning and not errors but I think that this is the reason why plugin doesnt work. I believe that there is only some problem with my htaccess file. Right now it is only basic WP htaccess file and it looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

code from functions.php:

```
function get_file_data( $file, $default_headers, $context = '' ) {
    $fp = fopen( $file, 'r' );
    $file_data = fread( $fp, 8192 );
    fclose( $fp );
    $file_data = str_replace( "\r", "\n", $file_data );
    if ( $context && $extra_headers = apply_filters( "extra_{$context}_headers", array() ) ) {
        $extra_headers = array_combine( $extra_headers, $extra_headers ); // keys equal values
        $all_headers = array_merge( $extra_headers, (array) $default_headers );
    } else {
        $all_headers = $default_headers;
    }

    foreach ( $all_headers as $field => $regex ) {
        if ( preg_match( '/^[ \t\/*#@]*' . preg_quote( $regex, '/' ) . ':(.*)$/mi', $file_data, $match ) && $match[1] )
            $all_headers[ $field ] = _cleanup_header_comment( $match[1] );
        else
            $all_headers[ $field ] = '';
    }

    return $all_headers;
}
```

Any suggestions on this?

Thanks in forward.

Comment: Can you give some code from functions.php around line 3879?

Comment: I have added it to my post but it is only general functions.php file which comes with WP so I dont think the problem should be there. I believe it has to do something with htaccess headers.

Comment: fopen doesn't look to htaccess as it uses a local path. Can you check manually if the path structure is correct and the file exists?

Comment: yes both files exists

Comment: however the site that should be displaying xml feed sometimes display part of it as I wrote but also sometimes gives proxy error saying "The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server. The proxy server could not handle the request GET /index.php. Reason: Error reading from remote server"

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the errors because the file you are trying to `fopen()` does not exist - according to the log it is trying to open `/nfsmnt/hosting1_2/0/3/031ab609-b23c-40f3-8d1b-6700b9221820/auto-flex.eu/web/wp-content/plugins/ankona-fields-polia/polia.php`

The next errors for `fread()` and `fclose()` are because `fopen()` returned `false` rather than a file handle.